# How to make a colored circle pointer with white center in Apache eCharts?

Tags: echarts

I'm trying to re-create this example picture using Apache eCharts:

[image]

This is what my Apache eCharts version looks like so far:

[image]

As you can see, I have almost finished re-creating it.

The only part I can't figure out is how to make the small circle pointer to be a colored circle with white center. The color of the pointer should match the color of axis line it is on.

Currently mine is grey, which doesn't look good.

Here is my code:

```JavaScript
const gaugeOption = {
  series: [
    {
      data: gaugeData,
      type: 'gauge',
      startAngle: 180,
      endAngle: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      splitNumber: 3,
      pointer: {
        icon: 'circle',
        length: '12%',
        width: 50,
        offsetCenter: [0, '-90%'],
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          borderColor: 'auto', // This doesn't work :(
          borderWidth: 5,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.5)',
          shadowBlur: 2,
          shadowOffsetY: 1,
        },
      },
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        roundCap: true,
        lineStyle: {
          width: 9,
          color: [
            [0.5, '#e76262'],
            [0.54],
            [0.66, '#f9cf4a'],
            [0.7],
            [0.83, '#eca336'],
            [0.87],
            [1, '#3ece80'],
          ],
        },
      },
      axisTick: {
        length: 2,
        lineStyle: {
          color: '#8a94a6',
          width: 2,
        },
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisLabel: {
        show: false,
      },
      title: {
        show: false,
      },
      detail: {
        rich: {
          header: {
            fontSize: 36,
            fontWeight: 700,
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            color: '#0a1f44',
          },
          subHeader: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 400,
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            color: '#8a94a6',
          },
        },
        formatter: ['{header|{value}}', '{subHeader|15-30-2022}'].join('\n'),
        offsetCenter: [0, '-20%'],
        valueAnimation: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

EDIT:

I have also tried specifying the colors directly as per below. It makes no difference. The border or the circle pointer remains a grey color:

```
      pointer: {
        icon: 'circle',
        length: '12%',
        width: 50,
        offsetCenter: [0, '-90%'],
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          borderColor: [
            [0.5, '#e76262'],
            [0.66, '#f9cf4a'],
            [0.83, '#eca336'],
            [1, '#3ece80'],
          ],
          borderWidth: 5,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.5)',
          shadowBlur: 2,
          shadowOffsetY: 1,
        },
      },
```

The only way I can change it's color is to set it to a single static color, but that is not what I want, it should adapt to the color of the axis beneath it.

Comment: That's a shame 'auto' option doesn't work on the border color. But you can still set the border color to a variable that you change when the gauge value is changed, depending on it's new position.

Comment: Thanks that was a great idea! I didn't realise I could use variables. Do you want to add that as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `borderColor` to a variable. Then change this variable when the gauge value is changed, depending on its new position.

You'll also have to use `setOption()` to make the change effective on the chart.

```js
//update your variable however you want 
myBorderColor = '#f00'; 

//then make the change to the chart
myChart.setOption({
  series: [
    {
      pointer: {
        itemStyle : {
          borderColor: myBorderColor
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});
```